# Google Custom Search - don't want trunated title

Tags: javascript, search

I am trying to do a simple Google Search where I just get back the titles linked to the pages. I have bought the business search and I have everything working (see code below) - I just want to get the full title of the page, not the truncated title. Can anyone help me? 
In my head I have:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the Search API
google.load('search', '1');

// Set a callback to load the Custom Search Element when you page loads
google.setOnLoadCallback(
  function(){
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('011927268382499158334:cuvurabmo-o');

    // Use "mysite_" as a unique ID to override the default rendering.
    google.search.Csedr.addOverride("mysite_");

    // Draw the Custom Search Control in the div named "CSE"
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');

  },
true);
</script>
```

In the body I have:

```
<div style="display:none">

<!-- Return the unescaped result URL.-->
<div id="mysite_webResult" >
  <div class="gs-webResult gs-result"
    data-vars="{longUrl:function() {
      var i = unescapedUrl.indexOf(visibleUrl);
      return i < 1 ? visibleUrl : unescapedUrl.substring(i);}}">

    <!-- Build the result data structure.-->
    <table width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <!-- Append results within the table cell.-->
          <div class="gs-title">
            <a class="gs-title" style="color:#990000;font-family:'Times New Roman',serif;font-size:8.0pt;font-decoration:underline;" data-attr="{href:unescapedUrl,target:target}"
              data-body="html(title)"></a>
          </div>


          <!-- Render results.-->
          <div data-if="Vars.richSnippet && Vars.richSnippet.action" class="gs-actions"
            data-body="render('action',richSnippet,{url:unescapedUrl,target:target})"></div>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Div container for the searcher.-->
<div id="cse"></div>
```